# How to stop lose focus on RDP after close RDP app and make mouse working

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

How to stop lose focus on RDP after close RDP app and make mouse working. I have macro on RDP and when close Remote Desktop Application macro not working because lose focus. Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Consider redesigning your workflow so that you aren't dependant on the GUI, that is always going to be a fragile approach.  One interim workaround might be to connect to the Remote Desktop server running your workflow (A) *via* another Remote Desktop server (B) and then disconnecting your client from B while leaving A and B connected.  I'm not absolutely certain, but I *think* that would trick server A into thinking that the desktop is still visible and stop the Windows GUI from turning itself off.

Comment: ... as far as I know it isn't possible to make the Windows GUI work properly in a disconnected/locked/noninteractive session, but if anybody knows differently, please do post an answer!  That would potentially solve a major problem I'm facing at work just now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you close the RDP app you are actually disconnecting that session.  Your macro will not continue to run in the background because your session is no longer active.  If you want it to continue running you need to keep your RDP session active and logged in.

Comment: Not possible to make session still active after disconnect?

Comment: No.  It's no longer an interactive session.  You could run something as a service if you want it to continue running.

Comment: It isn't quite that simple.  Applications do continue to run in disconnected sessions, you can leave a number-crunching job running for example and reconnect to it later.  But for some reason I've never quite understood, the Windows GUI isn't fully operational if the desktop isn't at least nominally visible.  I don't think using a service would solve the problem, pretty sure all non-interactive desktops have the same limitations in this respect.

Comment: This is true.  Apps do stay open, but I think anything that is interacting with the GUI is going to stop.  It depends what your macro is doing I guess.

Comment: Yes, now I try to another PC and resolution is changed. It is possible to use GUI and same resolution after disconnect?